# Merge python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have around 1000 of dictionary like this.

```
x = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':5}
y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
z = {'e':5, 'b': 2}
```

I want a merged dictionary like this.

```
f = {'a':[1,0,0], 'b': [2,10,2], 'c':[5,11,0], 'e':[0,0,5]}
```

Is there a iterative way to do this.? After creating the final dictionary i want to create a matrix where a , b, c, e will be the column heading with three rows as shown below:

```
a  b  c e
1  2  5 0
0 10 11 0
0  2  0 5
```

Comment: where are 0's coming from? Also why are the 0's before `5` in the last list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e')
dicts = (x, y, z)
f = {k: [d.get(k, 0) for d in dicts] for k in keys}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
f = {k: [d.get(k, 0) for d in (x, y, z)] for k in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e')}
```

Comment: Here we know that there are 3 dictionaries.What if there are 1000 of dictionaries and thousands of key.Here we are mentioning five keys i.e a,b,c,e but in general i have more than 1000 keys.@Steven Rumbalski

Comment: @rombi Then use the first solution that he suggested.

Comment: How can i use first solution.In first solution we have to manually enter the keys.I have like 900 keys from 1000 dictionaries.? What to do.? @sarith

Comment: Assuming you have a collection of dictionaries called `dicts` then do  `keys = set(k  for d in dicts for k in d)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your keys with [`dict.viewkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) and a `reduce` function, then use `collections.defaultdict` to append the corresponding values to keys :

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':5}
>>> y = {'b':10, 'c': 11}
>>> z = {'e':5, 'b': 2}
>>> l=[x,y,z]

>>> keys=reduce(lambda i,j: i | j ,[j.viewkeys() for j in l])
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k in keys :
...    for i in l:
...        d[k].append(i.get(k,0))
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 0, 0], 'c': [5, 11, 0], 'b': [2, 10, 2], 'e': [0, 0, 5]})
```

Then you can create the proper matrix :

```
>>> [[i]+j for i,j in d.items()]
[['a', 1, 0, 0], ['c', 5, 11, 0], ['b', 2, 10, 2], ['e', 0, 0, 5]]
```

Comment: What if i have thousands of dictionaries like x,y,z. What should be my course of action then.? @Kasra

Comment: @rombi then you can put them in list `l`. and how you get your dictionary? did you get them from a file? or database?

Comment: What about keys then ? How to initialize keys variable.? Actually i am parsing different documents , therefore different dictionary for every document. @Kasra

Comment: @rombi for `keys` you just need `l` so you can calculate it if you have `l`. do you mean it?

Comment: Sorry i am not able to get it . Can You write the code for initializing keys variable. @Kasra

Comment: @rombi can you put all of your dicts in a list? at all?

Comment: That i can do. How to replace this line of code      **keys=reduce(lambda x,y: x | y ,[j.viewkeys() for j in l])**

Comment: @rombi why you want to replace that??? you just need to replace the `l` in `[j.viewkeys() for j in l]` with your new list name!

Comment: What about x and y ? @Kasra

Comment: @rombi ahaan! those are just variable name for `lambda` function!

Comment: Thanks very much. I am new to this,hence i confused it with dictionary name.:) @Kasra

Comment: The list i am creating looks like this l=['x','y','z']. This error is coming `" 'str' object has no attribute 'viewkeys' "`. How to create a list that looks like this
l=[x,y,z] without any apostrophe.@Kasra

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to perform the two tasks:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts = [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c':5},
         {'b':10, 'c': 11},
         {'e':5, 'b': 2}]

# determine what keys exist in the dictionaries and sort them
keys = sorted(reduce(lambda a,b: a|b, (set(d) for d in dicts)))

f = defaultdict(list)
for k in keys:
    for d in dicts:
        f[k].append(d.get(k, 0))

print 'merged\n  f: {}'.format(dict(f))

matrix = [keys] + [[d.get(k, 0) for k in keys] for d in dicts]
print '\nmatrix:'
for row in matrix:
    print ' '.join('{:>2}'.format(elem) for elem in row)
```

Output:

```
merged
  f: {'a': [1, 0, 0], 'c': [5, 11, 0], 'b': [2, 10, 2], 'e': [0, 0, 5]}

matrix:
 a  b  c  e
 1  2  5  0
 0 10 11  0
 0  2  0  5
```